# Add icon into WPF TextBox control

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, wpf-controls

Has anyone got a xaml example of how to add an icon into a TextBox control in WPF?

I'm specifically after overlaying an icon into the right hand side of a TextBox control but am not sure how to do it

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226098/366064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example, you can put that in a `Style` if you want to affect all your `TextBox` with the same `Template`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="Test">
        <TextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    <Image Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                           Source="http://fakeimg.pl/12x12/" 
                           Width="12" 
                           Height="12"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TextBox.Template>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, is there anyway to get the Image WITHIN the Textbox to the right?

Comment: Just add a `ColumnDefinitions` with 2 `ColumnDefinition` to the `Grid` inside the `ContentControl` and set `Grid.Column="1"` to the `Image` control. By doing so, you can also remove `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Image`.

Comment: So another question (sorry I'm rubbish with templating in wpf!)