# My Watermarker Style is blocking for my Textbox information

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am not sure how else to describe it.

Problem: I am running style For my WPF Textbox in the app.xaml

```
<Grid>
   <TextBox Style="{StaticResource WatermarkTextbox}" x:Name="Email" Height="30" Width="300" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="0 40 0 0" />
</Grid>
```

When i have the Style in my TextBox I cannot get the written informartion into my SQL. This is my style in App.xaml:

```
<local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InputToVisibility"/>
<Style x:Key="WatermarkTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                      <Grid>
                          <TextBlock Text="Email...">
                              <TextBlock.Visibility>
                                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource InputToVisibility}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="Email" Path="Text.IsEmpty"/>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Email" Path="IsFocused"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Visibility>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBox x:Name="Email" Background="Transparent"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It took some time to find this problem. And I am completely out of ideas at this point.

I got one aswell for my Password, for a login screen. But when I run the code to look for credentials it gives me nothing back. IF I remove the style it fixes all the problems for me. Anyone know of a way where I can keep the Waterstyle and make it work at the same time ?

C# Login button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Login
    {
       SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=LoginDB;Integrated Security=True");

        try
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();

            string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@UserName AND Password=@Password";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Email.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Pass.Text);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count == 1)
            {
                Main.Content = new Page1();
                Framep.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                GridS.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "App Information");
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

SQL:

```
go
USE [LoginDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUser](
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: I don't see `TemplateBinding` to `Text` property. When you read `Email.Text` it will not read `Text` from inner `TextBox`.

Comment: For correct way of templating your Controls look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates

Comment: You use a control template for your TextBox. That control template itself uses a TextBox to represent your TextBox, but it is NOT your TextBox. The TextBox used by the control template maintains its own Text property that is NOT linked to the Text property of your TextBox. Thus, while you enter the text into the TextBox that is part of the control template, the Text property of the TextBox **using** this control template is not being used, nor linked to the control template TextBox and thus remains unused/empty.Yeah, it is a bit of a mindf*uck, but that is what is the root of your problem.

Comment: Yeah I can see that. been reading up on the different things you guys have been saying. I kinda understand my mistakes. Though still not 100% sure on how I am supposed to fix it sadly. Still Kinda new to this.

Comment: At the link I provided... this part is doing the magic.  `<ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />` Copy that template to your project and modify it as you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply TextBox Control Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222421/how-to-apply-textbox-control-template)

Comment: I'm sorry.. Been reading through all of How to apply TextBox Control a few times But I just cannot seem to find the fix in there. Been trying a little templating binding and binding Path but I don't really think I know how to make that work out :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here!

I Modified your style a little bit to give you an idea of what to do.
I would say https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates is still the way to do it correctly!

```
<Style x:Key="WatermarkTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TxBlkEmail" Text="Email..." Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Trigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter TargetName="TxBlkEmail" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </Trigger.Setters>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                    <Trigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter TargetName="TxBlkEmail" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </Trigger.Setters>
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Comment: Yeah that seemed to do the trick! :D Amazing. Been fiddling around with a bunch of stuff. And that is all thanks to the ScrollViewer ?

Comment: As I told you in my previous comment, that will do the magic.