# TextBox, passwordBox and Button doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to c#.I created a simple login page in wpf.The TextBox, passwordBox and Button doesn't accept any input.I need a transparent text "PassWord" in PasswordBox.And I have also tried some animations and Binding.

Please try compiling the code in your system for better understanding of my problem.

Can someone help me with what's wrong in my code ?

Thanks in advance

Here is what I have tried.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="#FFDDE9F7"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="710" Width="660">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ChangeNextButtonColor" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="CadetBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="46" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="0,0,1,0">
        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="642" Margin="22,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="607" Background="White" CornerRadius="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Border BorderBrush="BurlyWood" BorderThickness="8" Margin="0,50,0,-2" CornerRadius="0,0,5,5" Background="BurlyWood" >
                <Grid>
                    <Border  BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="428" Margin="147,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" CornerRadius="13" Background="White" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Content="Sign Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="36" Foreground="BurlyWood" Height="92" Width="201" Margin="81,45,0,0"/>
                            <TextBox  Text="UserName" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="32,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="LightGray" />
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="BurlyWood" Margin="32,226,29,198"/>
                            <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="32,251,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="BurlyWood" Margin="32,289,29,135"/>
                            <!--<Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="80,338,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Background="CadetBlue" CornerRadius="8" />-->
                            <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,339,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="42" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Style="{StaticResource ChangeNextButtonColor}" Foreground="White" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Image Source="D:\Users\Nivr\Downloads\fasetto-word-69f144a73638b5c789d8df155cd023a6ad68f5e7\Source\Fasetto.Word\Images\Backgrounds\emoji-background.png" Canvas.Left="-4" Canvas.Top="9" Width="603" Margin="-6,-12,-8,-5"/>
                    <Label Content="Haffun" Canvas.Left="255" Canvas.Top="193" RenderTransformOrigin="0.485,0.647" Height="36" Width="119" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Tempus Sans ITC" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB9B0B0" Margin="250,183,220,357"/>
                    <Label Content="I already have an account " FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.069,0.29" Canvas.Left="171" Canvas.Top="502" Foreground="White" Margin="180,501,158,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <Label Content="ABCD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Pristina" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="36"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Watermarker Style is blocking for my Textbox information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060707/my-watermarker-style-is-blocking-for-my-textbox-information)

Comment: Why is your UserName TextBox readonly ?

Comment: ReadOnly means that you cannot type anything in there

Comment: @NawedNabiZada oh ok.But still it is not accepting any input.

Comment: I may admit, this is not going to be easy to debug. Will you replace your inner grid with a StackPanel and remove all Margins. You might have different controls on top of each other.

Comment: Why are you adding an `Image` on top of the input controls...?

Comment: @mm8 Thanks.Now it works. `Image` should be added to the background.